# how to handle Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to create a function to create new user in my sql database but I'd like my usernames to be unique, I set a constraint to make it so my database refuse a duplicate of my username.

```js
// Create and Save a new User
exports.create = (req, res) => {
// Validate request
    if (!req.body) {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: "Content can not be empty!"
        });
    }


    // Create a User
    const user = new User({
        IdUtilisateur: generator.generateID(),
        UserName: req.body.UserName,
        Name: req.body.Name,
        FirstName: req.body.FirstName,
        Password: generator.generatePwd(),
        Acces: req.body.Acces
    });

    // Save User in the database
    User.create(user, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the User."
            });
        }else res.status(201).send(data);
    });
}
```

now in my code when I try to create a new user with a username that already exist I get an error sent in response:

`"message": "ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'Nname' for key 'UserName'"`

I'd like to know how to handle this special case, so that if I get this precise error I can maybe do something like trying again but adding an int at the end or anything, so how can I test this mysql error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this you can use. I suppose a cleaner way to write code.
Which will improve more readability.

```
// Create and Save a new User
exports.create = (req, res) => {
// Validate request
    if (!req.body) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          success: false,
          message: "Content can not be empty!"
        });
    }

    const userDetails = {
        IdUtilisateur: generator.generateID(),
        UserName: req.body.UserName,
        Name: req.body.Name,
        FirstName: req.body.FirstName,
        Password: generator.generatePwd(),
        Acces: req.body.Access
    }


    // Create a User
    const user = new User(userDetails);

    // Save User in the database
    User.create(user, (err, data) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log("Error while creating new entry", err);
            return res.status(500).json({
              success: false,
              message: (err.code == 'ER_DUP_ENTRY' || err.errno == 1062) ? "Username already exists!" : "Unknown error"
            });
        } 
        
        return res.status(201).send({
          success: true, 
          msg: "Data inserted successfully"
        });
    });
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can add errno key and check in frontend.

Comment: I'm trying to get the api create the new username and I'm trying to find some way to recognize this error but I think you gave me the answer using err.code might be the solution

Answer (score 0):

To parse the err message that MySQL returns to nodejs and handle further the request body I use this way:

```
try {
    await query('INSERT INTO some_table SET ?', ctx.request.body)
    ctx.status = 201;
    ctx.body = 'ok';
} catch (err) {
    if (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(err)).code === ('ER_DUP_ENTRY')) {
        ctx.body = 'record already exists';
    } else {
        ctx.throw(400);
    }
}
```